# knex - how to select data with multiple where clause

Tags: knex.js

I need to select something like this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE email = ''
  AND (received = null || received = '') 
  AND orderNumber = ''
```

How to do this in knex ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#where), you can use `andWhere` with a function inside to declare a `or`

```js
const query = knex.select('*')
  .from('table_name')
  .where('email', '')
  .andWhere('orderNumber', '')
  .andWhere(function() {
    this.where('received', null)
      .orWhere('received', '')
  })
  .andWhere('orderNumber', '');
```